# How to get R list column names from C code

Tags: c++, r

I need to write a C/C++ function that will retrieve R list column names.

From R I want to do the following.

```
> dyn.load("R_list.dll")
> x = list(param1="value1", param2="value2", param3="value3")
> .Call("func", x)
```

and as an output I want to see `"param1" "param2" "param3"` as `names(x)` function does from R

`> names(x)
[1] "param1" "param2" "param3"`

In my cpp file I have the following

```
#include <R.h>
#include <Rinternals.h>
#include <Rdefines.h>

extern "C" __declspec( dllexport ) SEXP func(SEXP list)
{
    try
    {
        if (isNewList(list))
        {
            int n = length(list);
            printf("%d\n", n);
            for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
                printf("%s\n", CHAR(STRING_ELT(VECTOR_ELT(list, i), 0)));
        }
        else
        {
            throw std::exception("'list' variable must be a list!");
        }       
    }
    catch(const std::exception& ex)
    {
        printf("Exception was thrown: %s\n", ex.what());
    }
    return R_NilValue;
}
```

How to get column names, not the values, from C/C++ code?

Comment: Unless your list is a data.frame (and it's not), you're probably after _element_ names, not column names.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's all there in `Rf_getAttrib`, `R_NamesSymbol`, see [Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-devel/R-exts.html#Attributes):

```
library('inline')
listnames <- cfunction(signature(x="list"), "
   return Rf_getAttrib(x, R_NamesSymbol);
")

listnames(list(param1="value1", param2="value2", param3="value3"))
## [1] "param1" "param2" "param3"
```

As you see, `Rf_getAttrib` returns an ordinary character vector here, which may be manipulated with `STRING_ELT`.

Answer (score 2):

Even shorter -- one statement as Rcpp takes care of all the conversions.

First load Rcpp:

```
R> library(Rcpp)
```

The create our one-statement function

```
R> cppFunction('CharacterVector mynames(List l) { return l.attr("names"); }')
```

and test it:

```
R> mynames(list(a=1:3, b=runif(10), c=LETTERS))
[1] "a" "b" "c"
R>
```

*Edit:* As Romain reminded me, an even shorter variant is using `names()`:

```
R> cppFunction('CharacterVector mynames(List l) { return l.names(); }') 
R> mynames(list(a=1:3, b=runif(10), c=LETTERS))
[1] "a" "b" "c"
R>
```

Comment: You can do `l.names()` even.

Answer (score 1):

The `attr` member function can also be used for this (although @gagolews' answer is clearly simpler):

```
require(inline)
l <- list(a=1:3, b=runif(10))
f <- cxxfunction(signature(x_ = "List"), plugin = "Rcpp", body = '
    Rcpp::List x(x_);
    CharacterVector names = x.attr("names");
    return names;
')
f(l)

# [1] "a" "b"
```

Comment: You can reduce that to one statement.